# How can change runtime colors in Apache Superset Line Chart

Tags: apache-superset

In the superset Line Chart how can I configure so that its run time colors should be changed on conditional based as in the attached screenshot.

like

if AQI <= 100 then color = green

if AQI between 101 and 200 then color = yellow

if AQI between 201 and 200 then color = pink

if AQI > 300 then color = red

tried to edit CSS but its not working

[image]

Comment: Anyone can you please update?